# Images not being rendered in rails 3.2.3 in controller

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

Hey i have a controller method show which has a footer partial in its layout .It consists of 2 images . Hence when

```
localhost:3000/jobs
```

is called and the same footer partial is rendered the images get displayed
but when localhost:3000/jobs/show/1 is called the footer images are not rendered. now it looks for /jobs/assets/twitter_32.png rather than assets/twitter_32.png

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you always use the `image_tag` helper to refer to images in the asset pipeline!

`<%= image_tag 'twitter_32.png' %>` in HTML/Erb

`image-url('twitter_32.png')` in SASS/CSS

This will always point to the correct image, especially when you have activated digest filenames in the asset pipeline (and this is activated by default).

See the [Asset pipeline guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Just set images source to `/assets/image.ext`. Right now you likely have it as `assets/image.ext`. This little slash makes all the difference.